# How to find count of numbers in a range that satisfies both X mod N = A and X mod M = B?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

For example how many numbers X are there from [0,100] that satisfies both X mod 8 = 2 and X mod 5 = 1.
My first approach was to find X such that X mod LCM(A,B) = (X mod A) + (X mod B). Because if a number is divisible by LCM(A,B) that means it's a multiple of A as well as B. And as for remainder the assumption that X mod LCM(A,B) will be equal to the summation of individual remainders X mod A and X mod B was made out of thin air. For example to find X's where X mod 3 = 2 and X mod 2 = 0 it works. But for example X mod 8 = 2 and X mod 5 = 1, LCM(8,5) = 40. 26 mod 8 = 2 and 26 mod 5 = 1 but with this approach 26 will never be an answer. So obviously it's not correct.

Comment: Cf. the [Chinese remainder theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem#Case_of_two_moduli)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that if you find one solution for $x \equiv 2 \pmod{8}$ and $x \equiv 1 \pmod{5}$, the other solutions will cycle every $40$. This is because the LCM of the two moduli is $40$ and therefore each solution will be a sum of a factor of $40$ greater (or less) than your result.

You can find that $26$ is one solution. From there, all other solutions are in the form $26+40n$, where $n$ is an integer. Obviously in the domain from $0$ to $100$, there are two solutions, namely $26$ and $66$.

Now, take the example that you don't get a trivial solution. You have two congruences: $$x \equiv 2 \pmod{8}$$ $$x \equiv 1 \pmod{5}$$

Let $x = 8k+2$, by the first equation. Plugging it into the second equation gets us $8k+2 \equiv 1 \pmod{5}$, or $8k \equiv -1 \pmod{5}$, or $$8k \equiv 4 \pmod{5}.$$ Dividing both sides by $4$ gets us $2k \equiv 1 \pmod{5}$. From here, you still need to find a solution but luckily it's only one modulo, not two.

Note that $k = 3$ works. Substituting that into $x = 8k + 2$ gets us $x = 26$, and it cycles every $40$ for a final answer of $x = 26 + 40n$.

-FruDe

Comment: So when I find 26 as an answer total number of X's upto 100 will be just (100-26) / LCM(8,5). That is a good lead to a general solution. But is there a fast way to find one solution? It might happen that I have to consider thousands of numbers before I can find one solution.

Comment: @Sami Yes, I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Numbers in $[0,100]$ satisfying $x\operatorname{mod} 8 = 2$:
$$\{2, 10, 18, 26, 34, 42, 50, 58, 66, 74, 82, 90, 98\}$$
Numbers in $[0,100]$ satisfying $x\operatorname{mod} 5 = 1$:
$$\{1, 6, 11, 16, 21, 26, 31, 36, 41, 46, 51, 56, 61, 66, 71, 76, 81, 86, 91, 96\}$$

Numbers on both of these lists: $$\{26, 66\}$$

Comment: Is there a general approach? [0,100] range was just an example. For huge ranges finding all values by hand is not much helpful.